# Laravel - 404 for destroy launching GET on Vagrant

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-5

I'm bulding API Laravel 5 application with RESTful controllers. I have method `destroy` defined this way in controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    App::abort(404);
}
```

because at the moment I don't want to handle it. The strange thing is when I use such code, I get `404` header but also get output from my show method:

```
public function show($id)
{
   die('show method');
}
```

so when using DELETE method for my resource I get 404 code with output `show method`.

I'm 100% sure I'm launching destroy method, because if I put in my destroy method:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    die('destroy');
}
```

I will have displayed `destroy` with 200 status code

I'v tested it in PhpStorm but also with this [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) and in both cases result is the same.

The question is - what is going here and how to return just 404 code without data or with empty data?

**EDIT**

I've investigated this issue further and what I discovered. If I run my app on localhost with:

```
DELETE http://lara404/test/1
```

I get pure 404 error as it should be.

I copied exact same code and run it in Vagrant. I run url:

```
DELETE http://lara404.app/test/1
```

and now I'm getting 404 code with `abcdef` message.

The only things I changed in default installation is:

1) adding at the beginning of `routes.php`

```
$router->resource('test','TestController');
```

2) Putting into TestController the following code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App;

class TestController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        dd('xxx');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //

        return "abcdef";
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //

        App::abort(404);
    }

}
```

3) Commenting in `Kernel.php` line:

```
'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'
```

I've just checked it also with fresh installation of Laravel 5 (not using any specific commit) and exactly same happens - the same code launched on localhost works fine and the same code running on Vagrant goes to show method also

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue. I get the HTML of the 404 page as response. Have you tried it on a fresh installation already?

Comment: @lukasgeiter On fresh install it is working ok (I've just checked), but at the moment I need to use commit version in my `composer.json` file: `"laravel/framework": "dev-master#846c935194a036901ba6b4397c8897fa51e19111"`

Comment: I made an install of this version and still cannot reproduce the problem. I suppose you messed something up with this specific installation. Also what's the reason for using that fixed version?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I need to use https://github.com/caffeinated/modules and it doesn't work in new Laravel 5 - https://github.com/caffeinated/modules/issues/11 I will try with fresh install then and check if this error will show

Comment: @lukasgeiter I've modified my question. It seems this happens when running on Vagrant while on localhost it's fine

Comment: Strange. Does it happen with POST and PUT too?

Comment: @lukasgeiter If I put `App::abort(404);` to store and update methods for store (POST) I get only 404 as it should be, but for update (PUT) I also get 404 and `abcdef` string. And again, it only happens when running on Vagrant, on localhost it's fine - I got only 404 all the time

Answer (score 0):

You need this if using json -

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    return Response::json(null, 404);
}
```

Or this if not using json -

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    return Response::make("", 404);
}
```

Comment: I also tried this way, but I still get data from show method

Comment: Can you edit the question and put some more controller code ?